# IdentityServer External Identity Access token in SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to build SPA application based on user identities from multiple 3rd-party OpenId Connect / OAuth2.0 providers (for simplicity, let's assume users has to login via Google and Facebook). Also, I would like to have long-term access to user's resources (background server jobs, etc.)

So, desired architecture I would like to have looked like that:

SPA -> Web API -> IdentityServer4 ->  Facebook / Google / etc.

Is it possible to not only authenticate SPA using one of these 3rd-party identity providers but still have an ability to make requests from within Web API on behalf of the user? How should I manage external `access_token` in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by:  make requests from within Web API on behalf of the user?

Comment: @YahyaHussein: so, I want to schedule background server jobs from SPA applications. These background jobs will try to download some data from external services. For example:

User logs in SPA using Facebook and schedule data retreival task to execute every day.  The task will call Facebook API for data and save it to a database. All the jobs should be executed on Web API side.

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi did you figure out a decent way forward?